# after ubuntu update, docker got this error: cannot connect to the docker daemon. is the docker daemon running?

Tags: services, docker

before ubuntu update, docker runs automatically on boot. without needing me to log in and manually launch docker desktop.

but it work fine if i manually launch docker desktop after i log in.

anyway, without launching docker desktop,

sudo service docker status

says that docker.service is green / active (running)
but docker ps says cannot connect to the docker daemon. is the docker daemon running

Comment: Could you update your question to include which version of Ubuntu and Docker you’re using? This will make it easier to determine if there’s an extra step required 

Comment: Is your user added to the `docker` group?